# Leader selection for crowd of turtles (NetLogo)

Tags: netlogo

I am using NetLogo for a simulation in which i have to deal with many turtles each representing a robot. I need to find an algorithm for leader selection. I want to make leaders  in between the crowd which will ultimately lead crowd toward the predefined target. Or is there any other way to which any turtle dynamically changes its behavior to become a leader. Any one if could help.
As we see in the model library a model named "Flocking". In which a random turtles leads all turtles. But i don't need random turtle i need the leader which should be at center or at corners of crowd.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/q/25782908/86485

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two immediate possibilities: a `leader` breed, or an `is-leader?` turtle attribute.  Note that a turtle's breed can be changed dynamically, just like any other attribute.

If you will have multiple leaders you may need to keep track of who follows them.  Three ways to do this: a leader can maintain an agent set of followers, or each robot can have a `leader` attribute set to the appropriate leader (which might be `nobody` or `self` for a leader 'bot), or (as a more powerful variant of the second approach) you could create a directed links from each follower to its leader.

hth.

Comment: If I use is-leader? turtle attribute then which criteria i can use to elect/select a leader among a swarm of robots.

Comment: What criteria do you want to use? It's your model. “At center or at corners” doesn't really narrow it down.