# Leader selection from crowd of turtles NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

Is there any way that i should ask /  make the circled one turtles( robots ) that you are leaders now (i.e. setting is-leader? true for them ). As i am using `Robots-own [ is-leader? ]`
For reference please see this image.
[image]

Comment: What do the circled ones have in common, other than the fact that you drew a circle around them? It isn't obvious to me from the picture.

Comment: previously: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25619505/86485

Comment: Sir Seth, you are right there is no common pattern between the circled ones, but the pattern which i am thinking is that the number of leaders should be 5-10% of total population. Secondly the selected leaders should be approximate middle of the crowd which i circled (with green pen). Now the middle leader will guide the green circled crowd toward the predefined target. For ref see new **[pic](http://postimg.org/image/smjldch77/)**. 
In short my question is that is there any way i can ask middle turtle of a crowd to become a leader Or should i use "n-of 5 turltes" to became leader randomly.

Comment: `n-of 5 turtles` seems like a good start to me. If the randomly selected turtles aren't already in the middle of a crowd, that will probably change quickly if the other turtles start following them. You might modify it a little by using `in-radius` to make sure no other leaders are too close. If you want to identify existing crowds and select a turtle in the middle of each crowd, that's a big question. There is no single obvious algorithm for that, so you will have to design such an algorithm, and then implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your elaboration on your goal in your comments, but noting that Seth is (as usual) completely correct in his warnings, you could try the following:

```
turtles-own [is-leader?]

to setup
  ca
  ask n-of 50 patches [sprout 1]
  choose-leaders
end

to choose-leaders
  ask max-n-of 5 turtles [count turtles in-radius 3] [
    set is-leader? true
  ]
end
```

Comment: Caveat: this could put all the leaders in the same cluster of turtles if it's the only one that's densely populated.

Answer (score 1):

I can see no commonality between the circled turtles, except that they are circled.  I will therefore interpret the question to ask about how to interact with turtles via the GUI.  If you right click on a turtle, you can pick it from a menu, and then choose "Inspect" from the next menu.  This will bring up a dialogue box that includes all the turtle's attributes, including its custom attributes.  You can use this to set its `is-leader?` attribute to `true`.

hth.